# Bearer token out of an OAUTH setting - question about correct use of standards

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

The IANA registry of Authentication schemes (http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) states that the Bearer authentication scheme is defined in the context of the Oauth protocol.

Does it make sense using a bearer token without an OAuth setting?
For example: I want to call an API of another company;  we agree on a custom scheme for a JWT security token to add to an API call (for example, suppose you don't use an Authorization Server as OAUTH would require, we use another custom mechanism). The JWT is signed and encoded and added to an API call using the Authorization http header with a bearer authentication scheme.

The question is not if this can work, because I know it can and it is good enough from a security point of view (this is why I don't add much details about the real implementation).

My question is about use of the standards: from a formal point of view are we right if we declare a bearer token outside of an Oauth setting?
A second question could be: would it be possible to declare a custom authentication scheme, for example 'myBearer'?

Thank You,
Corrado Tamietti

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following a standard pattern for your B2B security. Usually this involves an Authorization Server, but if there isn't one, for reasons out of your control, then using tokens can still be useful, in order to:

- Communicate scopes to represent areas of data
- Communicate claims used for finer grained authorization rules

I would design a solution around the following rules:

1. Company B, who own the API, must issue the access tokens. Only they should have access to the private key used to issue them. They can then control privileges, time to live and other aspects.
2. Company A have to call a Company B endpoint to get an access token, which involves sending a credential. The token received should be fairly confidential and not contain sensitive data.
3. Company A then sends that access token to other Company B endpoints to access data.

Even if you keep OAuth behaviour light for the time being, this is a standard pattern that should fit nicely into your applications and support future extensibility.

**USE OF AUTHORIZATION HEADER**

The link you provided referenced OAuth 1.0, which used the OAUTH keyword
in the Authorization header - but very few people use OAuth v1 these days, partly because it is less web / mobile friendly than OAuth v2.

OAuth v2 best practice involves sending JWTs via the general HTTP mechanism of the Authorization header - see [this section from the draft OAuth 2.1 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-7.2.1).

If you are using standard JWTs (without more advanced features such as proof of possession) then using 'bearer' feels like the right option to me. This describes only how the API message credential is presented and does not have to mean that a full OAuth solution is in place.

**FURTHER DETAILS ON AUTHORIZATION AND B2B**

OAuth B2B APIs usually use the [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/), and if data sensitivity is high, step 2 often involves use of Mutual TLS. Here are some related links from the Curity Web Site:

- [Scopes in APIs](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/)
- [Claims in APIs](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/)
- [Financial Grade B2B APIs](https://curity.io/resources/learn/what-is-financial-grade/#sender-constrained-tokens)

Comment: Thank you Gary,
I agree this would be a nice pattern, similar to our one.

I have one more question: in the case you describe, would you 'declare' the bearer token authorization scheme, that is would you use a bearer token in the http authorization header with the described content even if the setting is not exactly OUAUTH, or would you 'declare' a custom authorization scheme, for example using a 'myAuthorization' http header for the token?

Please not the question is not only 'academic' because if you use the 'authorization' header you exclude the use of your scheme and OAUTH together.

Comment: I added a section to my answer above - I think the confusion was due to looking at the older OAuth 1.0 material - where the word 'OAUTH' was included in the header. This is not the case any more in OAuth 2.0, which is the standard these days.

Comment: Thank you Gary, you clarified that in your opinion it is possible use a bearer token in the Authorization header even if a not fully compliant OAUTH 2 solution is in place. This is what I was searching for. I just add that my intention was referring to version 2.0 of OAUTH in my question; actually, the link that I provided take you to the OAUTH 2.0 specs if you follow the link for the bearer authorization scheme. But no problem!